# Unable to install gazebo 1.2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all

My actual gazebo-version (1.02) cant open any .urdf-file correctly.
The terminal shows following:

> Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has
> no gazebo element Warning
> [parser.cc:291] DEPRECATED GAZEBO
> MODEL FILE On July 1st, 2012, this
> formate will no longer by supported
> Convert your files using the gzsdf
> command line tool You have been
> warned!

And the urdf object is not visible.
So I guessed i have to install gazebo 1.2. By using

> sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-simulator_gazebo

the terminal shows:

> E: Unable to locate package
> ros-fuerte-simulator_gazebo

How can I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46442/unable-to-install-gazebo-1.2/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2012-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-10-22**:
What OS are you on? And what are your apt sources set to?

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2012-10-23**:
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. But I'm a Rookie in Linux.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2012-10-23**:
My Sources are set to: sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list' like its proposed here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2012-10-23**:
My Sources are set to:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That warning has been present for a while, but it is a warning not an error.

There must be some other reason why your simulation is not working.

About Gazebo 1.2:

> Work [has] been done to bring us
> towards the more stable underlying
> gazebo release (1.2.x), but there's
> [one more critical
> task](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/82/add-support-for-pre-gazebo-10x-model-xml) and some more testing before switching
> over. @hsu

It can be installed from source, but I must highlight the strongly worded caution that ["ROS Users: Never install Gazebo from here"](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.2/install), so you probably shouldn't do so unless you really know what you're doing.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello viovio,

the right syntax to install gazebo is

$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo **(Note the - instead of the _ )**

But as you I have the 1.0.2 version and many problems with it. And when running the command above, it tells that gazebo is up to date.

So I fear you can't install Gazebo 1.2 with ROS fuerte

---

Originally posted by [ad34](https://answers.ros.org/users/3449/ad34/) with karma: 11 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1